# Ruby hash use key value in default value

Tags: ruby, hash, default-value

I have the following code to create an array to object hash:

```
tp = TupleProfile.new(98, 99)
keyDict = Hash[Array[98,99] => tp]
keyDict[[98,99]].addLatency(0.45)
puts keyDict[[98,99]].getAvg()
```

This works, but I'd like to be able to call addLatency without checking for an existing hash value:

```
keyDict[[100,98]].addLatency(0.45) #throws error right now
```

So I want to create a default value that varies based on the key, something like:

```
keyDict = Hash.new(TupleProfile.new(theKey[0], theKey[1]))
```

Where theKey is some sort of special directive.  Is there any reasonably clean way to do this, or am I better off checking each time or making a wrapper class for the hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `Hash.new` block notation:

```
keyDict = Hash.new {|hash,key| hash[key] = TupleProfile.new(*key) }
```

Using the standard parameter notation (`Hash.new(xyz)`) will really only instantiate a single TupleProfile object for the hash; this way there will be one for each individual key.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, I think you might be able to use a [default procedure](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc).  The code in the default procedure will get run if you ask for a key that doesn't exist.  Here is an example using a tuple key:

```
class Test
  def initialize(a,b); @a = a; @b = b; end
  attr_accessor :a, :b
end

keyDict = {}

keyDict.default_proc = proc do |hash, (key1, key2)|
  hash[[key1, key2]] = Test.new(key1, key2)
end


keyDict[[99,200]]
 => #<Test:0x007f9681ad2720 @a=99, @b=200> 

keyDict[[99,200]].a
 => 99
```

Comment: I'm getting this error on the default_proc line: `undefined method \`default_proc=' for {}:Hash (NoMethodError)`

Comment: `default_proc=` was added in Ruby 1.9. Are you on 1.8?